# Follow link in vim with markdown syntax

Tags: vim, markdown

Is it possible to follow markdown links from vim with a keyboard shortcut? The links look like this:

```
[foo](relative/path/to/file.pdf)
[bar](www.some-webpage.com)
```

I want to have a keyboard shortcut that opens the links with the default application. Not sure whether it makes a difference, but I am using OS X.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try `gx` when your cursor is over the link. netrw should open the link with the external handler (see [`:h netrw-gx`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-gx)) which in Mac OS X will be [open](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html).

Comment: Use `gf` for "go to file" for file paths. See `:h gf`

Answer (score 4):

I have merged support for this into [Vim Markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/pull/183).

As explained on the README, it works from any of the following cursor positions:

```
[Example](http://example.com)
^  ^    ^^   ^       ^
1  2    34   5       6

<http://example.com>
^  ^               ^
1  2               3
```

My implementation uses the syntax of each position to find out the URL. The entry point is at: https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/blob/028a7613eadf84d4e75c2eaa87b1cc756774f9c5/ftplugin/mkd.vim#L472

Comment: This is nice, but what if the link is a link to a local file? `gf` doesn't work, you have to navigate to the actual file name. Also, what about links listed at the end like `[link name][1]`. And at the end `[1] some link`. Is there mapping to jump from in text link to the actual link listed later?

Comment: @A.Blizzard  I don't think I implemented local file back then. Would have been nice. Haven't touched that project in a while though. Not worth my time :-) Also have a look at the issue tracker.